# How to Install Python a Packages List?

Tags: python, installation, pip

Please, could you help me? I want to install the same list of packages with each version of:

Python 3.9.0.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Tp9NYUYWzqAfI-IdYs3Wy_Yl90oX97Pb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103830166600409902837&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
pip3 list
Package                   Version
------------------------- --------
altgraph                  0.17.2
apyori                    1.1.2
argon2-cffi               21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0
attrs                     21.2.0
backcall                  0.2.0
bleach                    4.1.0
brewer2mpl                1.4.1
cffi                      1.15.0
colorama                  0.4.4
cryptography              35.0.0
cycler                    0.11.0
debugpy                   1.5.1
decorator                 5.1.0
defusedxml                0.7.1
dplython                  0.0.7
entrypoints               0.3
fonttools                 4.28.3
future                    0.18.2
ggplot                    0.11.5
graphviz                  0.19.1
ipykernel                 6.6.0
ipython                   7.30.1
ipython-genutils          0.2.0
ipywidgets                7.6.5
jedi                      0.18.1
Jinja2                    3.0.3
joblib                    1.1.0
jsonschema                4.2.1
jupyter                   1.0.0
jupyter-client            7.1.0
jupyter-console           6.4.0
jupyter-core              4.9.1
jupyterlab-pygments       0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets        1.0.2
kiwisolver                1.3.2
MarkupSafe                2.0.1
matplotlib                3.5.1
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3
missingno                 0.5.0
mistune                   0.8.4
nbclient                  0.5.9
nbconvert                 6.3.0
nbformat                  5.1.3
nest-asyncio              1.5.4
notebook                  6.4.6
numpy                     1.21.3
packaging                 21.3
pandas                    1.3.4
pandocfilters             1.5.0
parso                     0.8.3
patsy                     0.5.2
pefile                    2021.9.3
pickleshare               0.7.5
Pillow                    8.4.0
pip                       21.3.1
prometheus-client         0.12.0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.24
pycparser                 2.20
pydotplus                 2.0.2
pyfim                     6.28
Pygments                  2.10.0
pyinstaller               4.5.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.3
pyparsing                 3.0.6
pyrsistent                0.18.0
python-dateutil           2.8.2
pytz                      2021.3
pywin32                   302
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
pywinpty                  1.1.6
pyzmq                     22.3.0
qtconsole                 5.2.1
QtPy                      1.11.3
scikit-learn              1.0.1
scipy                     1.7.3
seaborn                   0.11.2
Send2Trash                1.8.0
setuptools                49.2.1
six                       1.16.0
sklearn                   0.0
statsmodels               0.13.1
terminado                 0.12.1
testpath                  0.5.0
threadpoolctl             3.0.0
tinyaes                   1.0.1
tornado                   6.1
tqdm                      4.62.3
traitlets                 5.1.1
wcwidth                   0.2.5
webencodings              0.5.1
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2
XlsxWriter                3.0.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
```

Install the same version of packages

But I need to install all packages at same time. I know that I can install for example pip install Some Package[PDF]==3.0.
Besides, some packages have dependencies so for example Pandas.
pip install pandas== 1.3.4, so It will install  pandas== 1.3.4, but also,  new version of dependences:
Package         Version

---

numpy           1.24.2
pandas          1.3.4
pip             20.2.3
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2022.7.1
setuptools      49.2.1
six             1.16.0
(e.g. But I need to install numpy                     1.21.3).

Comment: What have you tried?  The `pip` command line is pretty clear.

Comment: I need to install all packages at same time with same version. If I install each package, it will install new version of dependencies. For example (pip install pandas== 1.3.4), numpy 1.24.2, but I need numpy 1.21.3.

Comment: Why do you think you need that?  If pandas 1.3.4 needs numpy 1.24.2, then you absolutely need numpy 1.24.2.

Answer (score 1):

Dump all the packages into a requirements.txt file: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
Now install in the target environment using: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Hi bleuatb. Thank you so much for your help. I very new in Python and so on.